# Are there risks to auto-login/passwordless login other than physical access control?

Tags: security, autologin, kdm

Does auto-login/passwordless login leave the computer in exactly that same state as it would be after manually logging in, or does it create security risks of a type other than physical access control? I understand there are many ways to accomplish auto-login. If it makes a difference for this answer, I'm referring to doing it via settings in the KDM login manager. (Debian Wheezy)